# Update parent control when the child control is manually removed in the designer

Tags: c#, compact-framework, design-time

I am writing a custom control for Windows Mobile 6 devices with the Compact Framework 3.5 in C#. The control I am writing represents a list of buttons, let's call it **ButtonList** and the buttons **ButtonListItem**.

The list of ButtonListItem is editable in the designer through the collection editor:

[image: Visual Studio Designer Items Collection]

I set it up so that the ButtonList is updated and repainted when a ButtonListItem is added or removed in the collection editor.

**Here is the problem:**

When I delete a ButtonListItem manually by selecting it with the mouse and pressing the delete button in the designer, the the internal state of the ButtonList is not updated.

My goal is to make the manual deletion in the designer behave like a removal in the collection editor.

An example would be the TabControl class where removal of tab pages in the collection editor and manual deletion behave exactly the same.

How would you achieve this?

---

Edit 1: Simplified code for adding and removing a ButtonListItem to the ButtonList

```
class ButtonList : ContainerControl
{        
    public ButtonListItemCollection Items { get; private set; } // Implements IList and has events for adding and removing items

    public ButtonList()
    {
        this.Items.ItemAdded += new EventHandler<ButtonListItemEventArgs>(
            delegate(object sender, ButtonListItemEventArgs e)
            {
                // Set position of e.Item, do more stuff with e.Item ...

                this.Controls.Add(e.Item);   
            });

        this.Items.ItemRemoved += new EventHandler<ButtonListItemEventArgs>(
            delegate(object sender, ButtonListItemEventArgs e)
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(e.Item); 
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: You may simply need to refresh the device. What does your code look like that handles object adding and deletion?

Comment: Hi. The problem I mentioned happens only at design time before any deployment. So there would be no use in refreshing the Windows Mobile 6 device. I edited a bit of source code into my question nevertheless.

Comment: Apply the [Browsable(false)] attribute to the Items property so it doesn't show up in the designer.  There's no point in having it visible, the designer already supports adding and remove controls.

Comment: If I mark it [Browsable(false)] (in CF you have to do that in a seperate xmta file) then obviously the "Items | (Collection)" entry disappears from the property list. But this property is essential for adding ButtonListItems to the list at design time.

Comment: It's not just a matter of dragging and dropping stuff onto the ButtonList control. The control handles positioning and potentially formatting of its ButtonListItems just like a TabControl handles positioning and formatting of its TabPages. But to do that you have to use the "Items | (Collection)" property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap it up, I found a solution to my problem. Like a TabControl, my ButtonList contains two collections:

1. ControlCollection inherited from the Control class
2. ButtonListItemCollection (TabControl has TabPageCollection)

Adding ButtonListItems is done via the collection editor in the properties. Removing can be done either in the collection editor or just by selecting the ButtonListItem in the designer and pressing the *DEL* button on the keyboard (manual deletion).

When using the collection editor, ButtonListItems are added/removed to/from the ButtonListItemCollection and then to/from the ControlCollection.

However, when a ButtonListItem is manually deleted it is only deleted from the ControlCollection **not from the ButtonListItemCollection**. So what needs to be done is to detect when the ButtonListItemCollection holds ButtonListItems which are not in the ControlCollection.

Unfortunately in the Compact Framework there is no such thing as a ControlRemoved event in the Control class. So one solution would look like this:

```
class ButtonList : ContainerControl
{
    // ...

    public ButtonListItemCollection Items { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        if (this.Site.DesignMode)
        {
            this.Items.RemoveAll(x => !this.Controls.Contains(x));
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Hope that helps anyone working with the compact framework.